# htaccess rewrite engine with get

Tags: php, .htaccess, webserver

Following problem:
My `.htaccess` is looking like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule "^user/([A-Z a-z 0-9_\-.]{1,})((/\w+)+|/?)$" "display_content/user/profile.php?name=$1"
```

In the last rule URLs are redirected from `/user/blabla` to `/display_content/user/profile.php?name=blabla`. But now I would like that if you enter `/user/blabla/posts/` that you land on e.g. `/display_content/user/posts.php?name=blabla`. Does anyone have an idea how to realize this?

Thanks already :)

And oh sry its my first question on stack overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to pack this into the first rewrite rule but create a second one like this:

```
RewriteRule "^user/([\w\-.]+)/posts/?$" "display_content/user/posts.php?name=$1"
```

Along that lines, I would suggest reworking the first rule; it seems to contain unnecessary patterns: `RewriteRule "^user/([\w\-.]+)/?$" "display_content/user/profile.php?name=$1"`